# Which Ubuntu distribution should I install on my PC

Tags: system-installation, hp

I am new to Ubuntu, but I want to try some flavor of it. My issue is that I don't know which distribution of Ubuntu should I go for.

My PC has the following specs.:

```
HP Pavilion Media Center a6037.fr  
Ref.: RY906AA  
Date: 20.03.2007  
Motherboard:  ASUS - microATX - 24,4 cm (9,6 po) x 24,4 cm (9,6 po)  
Chipset : Intel 945G Intel Core 2 Duo, 1,8 GHz  
Socket : 775  
2 GB; PC2-4 200 Mo/s
```

Could you please give me some information?

Comment: The only info that is interesting (my opinion) is CPU (model, cores, frequency), RAM (size, type/speed), HDD (size, SSD?) and graphics card (model, memory, GPU). I would decide on a flavour based on the age too, as it roughly represents the overall state of your machine. Yours should probably run with standard Ubuntu, but a more lightweight OS might be a good decision depending on how intensive the work is you do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Version 14.04 is the newest stable version of ubuntu and is probably the best stable version out right now.

If you have more than 2GB of ram, go with the "amd64" (even though you have intel this is for all 64 bit systems) version. If less than 2GB of ram, you are probably better off with version i386 instead.

As far as flavors go, the installation media will allow you to "try ubuntu without installing" and all you have to do is choose this option before you start. You should try each of these flavors out to see which one works best on your setup and which one you like to use the best.

http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Other flavors:

[ubuntustudio](http://ubuntustudio.org/)

[Gnome Shell](http://ubuntugnome.org/)

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)

[Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)

[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

Ubuntustudio, Xubuntu, and Lubuntu all run really well on new or older machines and are optimised for performance with little required resources. Gnome Shell Ubuntu standard (Unity) and Kubuntu use more resources but provide a more interactive desktop and user experience.